# How to "freeze" particle system without convert operation

Tags: particles

I made 4 particle systems for one object in order to emit some stones on the ground (smaller and bigger). The system makes stones fall on the ground (with collision). 
I want to keep all the particles (stones) still at the exact postion (ie. frame 40) but WITHOUT convert operation. Convert operation need tons of additional memory which i don't have (and everything runs super slow). 
How to "freeze" particle systems without conversion in specific position (frame) so I can run other animation and simulations in the scene?

*or maybe there is another way to generate particles on the ground which are not generated IN the ground (as the plane of ground is crosscutting them in unnatural way).

Thx

Comment: 4GB on GPU and 16 RAM. But It is not about memory. It is about general idea how to solve it. I guess there must be some very simple solution to just "freeze" it etc.

Comment: Um change end the particle cache at a certain time.